# Destination and RelayState difference in SAML 2.0

Tags: saml, saml-2.0

I know that a lot of service providers use relay state as a way to keep track of what resource was accessed while SP initiated SSO, so SP can redirect to it after SAML assertion consumption.

However, I am looking at **Destination** attribute of SAML response and it looks like it was designed specifically for this case.

Am I missing something? Why service providers use Relay state in this way (vs using **destination**)?

Answer (score 12):

As you said, `RelayState` is a location where SP redirect the user once successful SAML authentication process completed.

But `Destination` attribute (related to Binding/Transport of SAML) required when message is signed.

From section **3.4.5.2 Security Considerations** of [SAML Bindings spec](https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-bindings-2.0-os.pdf#page=19):

> If the message is signed, the Destination XML attribute in the root
> SAML element of the protocol message MUST contain the URL to which the
> sender has instructed the user agent to deliver the message. The
> recipient MUST then verify that the value matches the location at
> which the message has been received.

This is primarily to avoid if somebody retrieves the SAMLResponse sent by IdP in the middle and send that message to other SP party for which the SAMLResponse is not created and send for.

If Destination included in the SAMLResponse (which is signed as well), then the intended SP (the receiver) could verify the Destination attribute value matches to destination/location at which the SAMLResponse was received. Perhaps the intended SP knows the destination/location URL and they could validate whether these two values are equal. If they are equal, SAMLResponse is sent to intended SP by IdP and SP accept it, else SP has to reject the SAMLResponse.